# Он спустился в глубокий овраг(,) недалеко отсюда

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

Нужна ли запятая? И как трактовать *недалеко отсюда*: как несогласованное приложение, как обстоятельство, которое выполняет роль сопутствующего пояснения, или как уточняющую конструкцию? Или можно по-всякому трактовать, главное, правильно поставить запятую? И при какой трактовке не нужна запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне видится верным вариант без запятой: *Он спустился в глубокий овраг недалеко отсюда.* Недалеко отсюда - несогласованное определение. Никакого оборота нет, поэтому и запятой нет. Запятая была бы при причастном обороте: *Он спустился в глубокий овраг, находящийся  недалеко отсюда.*

Уточняющей конструкции не вижу:*Спустился (куда?) в глубокий овраг, (куда именно?)недалеко отсюда*. Но ведь он не спустился недалеко отсюда, а овраг находился недалеко отсюда, это не уточнение места спуска.

Как поясняющее обстоятельство возможно, но восприниматься это будет как разговорная конструкция или неполное предложение с пропуском "который располагался" или "это происходило".

Так что первый вариант всё-таки самый приемлемый, если нужна нормативная литературная конструкция.